# Someone else set up a trial Google Apps account on my domain. How can I get Google to disable it?

Tags: security, google-workspace, hacking, domain-hacks

I own my domain (say, `mydomain.com`) and administer it through my hosting provider. A couple of days ago, I started receiving mail from Google Apps addressed to `jyotioffsetjsm01@mydomain.com`. There's no such email address set up on my domain, and I guess all badly addressed emails to my domain get sent to my admin email address.

The emails (from `apps-noreply@google.com`) all say things like:

> "NotMyName, don't forget to add billing information for Google
>   Apps.... Your setup is almost complete - just one step remains."

Needless to say, I have not set up Google Apps on my domain. I'm concerned that someone has breached my account.

The support links in the Google email all ask me to login with my Google Apps account (which I obviously don't have). The alternative is to phone them, but that would incur overseas charges since I don't live in the US.

Should I be concerned? What should my next steps be? How can I access Google Apps support to let them know about this fake spammy attempt to get a Google Apps account on my domain?

Comment: Is `jyotioffsetjsm01` the actual email address?

Comment: There's nothing in any of the emails that says "if you didn't request this, click here?" Anyone can create an unverified Google Apps account for you... but Google won't make it "live" until you verify it (or, in this case, anti-verify it)

Comment: @w3dk yes, that's the email address the Google email was addressed to, minus the domain. That email addy doesn't exist on my domain, though.

Comment: @barrycarter, nope, nothing on the email says that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Reset the account password

Since you are the owner of the e-mail account you can always try to [reset the password for that Google Apps account](https://support.google.com/a/answer/33561).

### Support center pages

There are many pages on Google's support center that deals with this kind of stuff:

- [Reporting Abuse Incidents](https://support.google.com/a/answer/134413?hl=en) Deals with this kind of stuff. It says:

  > If you believe that someone else has signed up for Google Apps with your domain name, please follow [these steps](https://support.google.com/a/answer/96917) for contested domain names.
- [How are reports of abuse, spam, and technical problems handled?](https://support.google.com/a/answer/33389?hl=en)
  According to this, you can send an e-mail to **abuse@yourdomain.com** or **postmaster@yourdomain.com** that will be forwarded to Google.
- [Prevent & report phishing attacks](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/106318?hl=en) Here you can find many links directing you to possible actions you can take to report phishing attack.
- [Report suspected abuse on Google Cloud Platform](https://support.google.com/code/contact/cloud_platform_report) Where you can directly file a report.

Comment: This was very helpful. I'll come back and mark as accepted once I'm successful.

Comment: Literally minutes after contacting support, they called me and said someone probably signed up by mistake and that the domain was not verified, so I wasn't in any danger.